# Setting Up CNAME for Subdomain

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I need to direct a subdomain to another server.  It works fine for subdomain.domain.com but not for www.subdomain.domain.com - is it possible to point the "www" to the server IP as well as I know many users enter a "www" as well

Answer (score 3):

CNAME the www explicitly:

```
$ORIGIN domain.com.
subdomain IN CNAME destination.com.
www.subdomain IN CNAME destination.com.
```

Or use a wildcard if you really want anything (www.subdomain.domain.com, blah.subdomain.domain.com, etc.) redirected:

```
$ORIGIN domain.com.
subdomain IN CNAME destination.com.
*.subdomain IN CNAME destination.com.
```

Comment: * is pretty useful.  I hadn't thought of *.subdomain - kind of handy.

Comment: * can also be quite tricky. See Q 5.9 of the comp.protocols.tcp-ip.domains FAQ http://www.faqs.org/faqs/internet/tcp-ip/domains-faq/part2/